# Bootstrap hover on nav items 'div isn't display'?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I trying to show div(#list) when I hover on navbar `#categories` but I don't what's going wrong. It's not working, Even None of item I'm not getting list on display.

I'm trying to use `#main #div #this:hover + #list {}` but it's still not working.
I don't know where I'm going wrong.

How can I do it that When I hover on `#categories` I want to display `#list`.

Can anyone figure this out?

```css
#list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#list {
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 130px;
  display: none;
}

#main #div #this:hover #list {
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="main" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="div" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li id="this" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">categories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>


<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<nav id="main" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="div" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li id="this" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">categories</a>
        <ul id="list">
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
          <li>Banana</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

and style:

```
 #list {
    display: none;
}
#main #div #this:hover  > #list {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work if you move `#list` into `#this` like:

```
<li id="this" class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">categories</a>
  <div id="list">
    <ul>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Banana</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

**Demo**

```css
#list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#list {
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 130px;
  display: none;
}

#main #div #this:hover #list {
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="main" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="div" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li id="this" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">categories</a>
        <div id="list">
          <ul>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>
```

Comment: It's working but navbar button not working when `width < 700`. Is there other any way?

Comment: Ofcourse not, you don't have any logic in your code that would make it work.

Comment: What kind of logic you're taking about? Can I've understand?

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can do it like this

```js
$('#categories').hover(function(){
$('#list').slideDown();
$('#list').mouseleave(function(){
$('#list').slideUp();
})
})
```

```css
#list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#list {
  width: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 130px;
  display: none;
}

#main #div #this:hover #list {
  background: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="main" class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div id="div" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li id="categories" class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">categories</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<br>


<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right but now I'm not able click on `banana`(ul li)  . Exactly what I want.

Comment: @RohitDalal i change the code for you now u can select and click

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class onclick

```
 $(Onclick() {                     
  $(".navbar-toggler").click(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("active");     
  });
});
```

Then in CSS in-class active add DIsplay:block